# Access jQuery function from page elements generated in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little jQuery call that returns perfectly for my element bound to an on function:

```
$(".claim-detail a").on("click", function(){
...some stuff   
})
```

Then a little html:

```
<p class="claim-detail"><a href="#modal" data-toggle="modal">get the data</a></p>
```

Works perfectly.

But I need that claim-detail html to be generated in javascript.  And when I move it there, the html is generated on the page with no problem, but the jQuery function breaks entirely .  Doesn't matter which piece precedes which in the javascript.

Anything I'm doing obviously wrong?

Comment: Without the your code we cannot say what you are doing wrong. You have to create and add the elements before you bind the event handler. Then it will work.

Comment: No idea, because you don't show how you generated it on the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for dynamically generated elements that do not exist at DOM ready. Change your click handler to:

```
$(document).on("click", ".claim-detail a", function(){
```

Chances are (I'm saying this because we don't know how your code was generated) that your click handler was trying to bind to the element before it existed

Comment: No, you don't *have to* use event delegation. The elements just have to exist at the moment the handler is bound.

Comment: @FelixKling -- Edited answer, was typing when you commented

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<p class="claim-detail"><a onclick="myNewFunction()" href="#modal" data-toggle="modal">get the data</a></p>
```

Where my myNewFunction is the function you were using in the event. Other option is create the event when you actually finish creating the HTML id and/or classes in the DOM.